# How to use list parameters in Fulfillment

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have a composite entity named @flavorQuantity.
This entity collects the "flavors" present in the order and their "quantities", in phrases like "I want 2 cocoa and 1 pumpkin", like this:

want @sys.number:quantity @flavor:flavor and @sys.number:quantity @flavor:flavor

Dialogflow identifies these parameters ($quantity and $flavor) separately, as in the image:

[PT-BR =](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBGCa.png)  saborQuantidade = @flavorQuantity || Cacau = Cocoa || Punpkin = Abóbora

How can I use each of these parameters in Fulfillmment to set up a function that provides the total value of each item, to add up the total value of the order. Using the function below it does not recognize the name of the values ​​contained within the parameter @flavorQuantity.

**

```
function order (agent){

const quantity = agent.parameters.quantity;

const flavor = agent.parameters.flavor;

var total;

if (flavor == 'Cacau & Castanhas'){

total = 3*quantity;
```

**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried agent.**queryResult**.parameters.quantity?